# J2me Player, Play MP3 Files One After The Other

Tags: java, java-me, media-player, mmapi

I am unable to play an MP3 file one after the other, when 1 file finishes playing the other file needs to start. I am only able to start playing 1 file, when I put code to start the next file it just does nothing. For some reasons I cannot use `thread.sleep()` for the duration of file. Is there any other way to do this?

```
//this is the basic code..
playq(String fname){
pl =  Manager.createPlayer(stream,"audio/mpeg");
pl.realize();

pl.prefetch();

pl.start();

// what should i use here?? pls i don't want to use thread.sleep..
playagain(fname);
}
void playagain(String fname){
        try {

    pl.stop();
    pl.deallocate();
   pl.close();

} catch (Exception ex) {}
 //change file name and stream and..
        playq(mp3f);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code should ***NOT*** attempt to play the code from a `catch` block - for one thing, it's only going to be called *if an exception was generated* (You also generally shouldn't be blanket-catching `Exception` - use something more specific).

Are you sure you *can't* use `Thread.sleep()`?  Granted you're not really going to want to anyways (for instance, if the user can pause the clip...).

Instead, look into using the `PlayerListener` interface, and listen for `END_OF_MEDIA` events.

A *really basic* (as in, this isn't tested, and needs more work besides) example:

```
public class PlayerRunner implements PlayerListener {

    private final String[] songFiles;
    private int songIndex = 0;

    public PlayerRunner(String[] songs) {
        this.songFiles = songs;
    }

    public void start() {
        playerUpdate(null, null, null);
    }

    // This method is required by the PlayerListener interface
    public void playerUpdate(Player player, String event, Object eventData) {
        // The first time through all parameters will be blank/null...
        boolean nextSong = (event == null);
        if (event == PlayerListener.END_OF_MEDIA) {
            player.stop();
            player.dallocate();
            player.close();
            nextSong = index < songIndex.length;
        }

        if (nextSong) {
            String fileName = songFiles[index++];
            if (fileName != null) {
                Player pl = Manager.createPlayer(fileName, "audio/mpeg");
                pl.addPlayerListener(this);
                pl.realize();
                pl.prefetch();
                pl.start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that I'm not doing this completely correctly - I'm not doing exception handling, for example.  Also, without knowing more about your situation, I don't know what other things to worry about.  This should just be a simple answer to get you started looking at where you should be going with this.

(Also, I've never worked with the media player of JME, so I don't know any caveats about the GC there, etc).

Comment: How did you use `List<String>` in Java ME?

Comment: *winces* I said I'd never messed with Java ME, and this shows.  Changing to use an arraylist.